# Probability theory: symmetric difference. Prove the following: $ \mathbb P(A \triangle\ B \triangle C)= ....$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is necessary to prove that the symmetric difference:

$\mathbb P(A \triangle\ B \triangle C)= \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B) + \mathbb P(C) - 2 \mathbb P(A\cdot\ B) - 2 \mathbb P(A \cdot\ C) - 2 \mathbb P(B \cdot\ C) + 4 \mathbb P(A \cdot\ B \cdot\ C)$

Here is a picture of symmetric difference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xufrJ.png)

So, according to the picture i wrote this expression:

$A \triangle\ B \triangle\ C= ?$

$A= A \cdot\ B! \cdot\ C! + A \cdot\ B \cdot\ C! + A\cdot\ B\cdot\ C + A \cdot\ C \cdot\ B!   $

$B= B \cdot\ A! \cdot\ C! + A \cdot\ B \cdot\ C! + A\cdot\ B\cdot\ C + B \cdot\ C \cdot\ A!   $

$C= C \cdot\ A! \cdot\ B! + B \cdot\ C \cdot\ A! + A\cdot\ B\cdot\ C + A \cdot\ C \cdot\ B!   $

B!=not B

A!=not A

C!= not C

But what is the next step, i couldn't imagine!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are two events, then $E_1\Delta E_2=(E_1\cup E_2) \setminus (E_1\cap E_2)$. Therefore,
$$\mathbb P(E_1\Delta E_2)=\mathbb P(E_1)+\mathbb P(E_2)-2\mathbb P(E_1\cap E_2).
$$
Then use the fact that $A\Delta B\Delta C=(A\Delta B)\Delta C=:E_1\Delta E_2$.